# Identify a vertical arcade shooter from the very early 1980s

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game, arcade

I'm trying to identify an arcade game that I remember playing.

At the bottom was the player's rocket that you could move in left-right direction and possibly also a small amount up and down (not sure about this).

The attackers look different in each level, had a different color (always a single color) and attacked in a different formation, but always identical in the respective level. The quality of the graphics was similar to that of Space Invaders.

I can still remember two levels:

- One in which the attackers were yellow spaceships, visually similar to your own rocket, which simply came down in a vertical direction.
- Another where the attackers were green; the shape reminds me in the broadest sense of a fighter from Star Wars that destroys the Death Star.

  The green attackers here constantly hit hooks, both up and down, but the main direction of movement is downward.

If one of the attackers is still down, the level starts all over again.

Additional difficulty was a limited amount of fuel.

What was this game called?

Comment: could it be astro blaster? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfFwKCb3ZwA

Answer (score 20):

found it :)) it was Astro Fighter

[image]

[image]

Comment: Love it when one finds their own answer. Well done!

Comment: On a point of trivia which you may not care about at all, those green space ships are presumably reminding you of the [tie fighters](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tie+fighter&t=fpas&iax=images&ia=images) which *defended* the Death Star; the ships that attacked and destroyed it were [x-wings](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=x-wing&t=fpas&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images). Seeing that the game was released a couple of years after the first Star Wars movie, I suspect the resemblance was intentional.

Comment: Take a look at WinArcadia

Answer (score 10):

Looks a lot like [Enigma 2](https://www.arcade-museum.com/game_detail.php?game_id=7712)

[image]

Single color aliens, & the fact that very few vertical shooters have a fuel bar (Astro Blaster is another one) certainly helps.

Comment: a good guess! the quality of the graphics is similar, but it wasn't Enigma 2

Answer (score 7):

It sounds quite a bit like [Galaxian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxian).

[image: Galaxian image from Wikipedia]

Comment: no, it wasnt Galaxian.

Answer (score 3):

Ticking some, but not all, of the boxes is Gorf (Midway, 1981).

[Gorf arcade cabinet gameplay video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adN1P_8Scks&ab_channel=OldClassicRetroGaming)

Comment: no, it was not Gorf :(